# How to align arrows using CSS or jQuery or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to create something that looks like this:

[image: Four arrows are placed opposite from each other; the up arrow is at the top, the left at the left, right at the right, and down at the bottom. The space in the middle is empty.]

However, I can only get it to look like this:

[image: Four arrows are in a row: left, up, down, right.]

This is the code I'm using.

```
<div style="position:fixed;z-index:1;">
   <a class="left" href="javascript:{}"><img src="images/leftarrow.png"/></a> 
   <a class="top" href="javascript:{}"><img src="images/uparrow.png"/></a>
   <a class="bottom" href="javascript:{}"><img src="images/downarrow.png"/></a>
   <a class="right" href="javascript:{}"><img src="images/rightarrow.png"/></a>
</div>
```

How can I make it look like I want it to?

Comment: `align arrows` ?? what exactly do you mean ??

Comment: how you want to align arrows?? please describe!

Comment: did you understand now.Or i need to paste my image here

Comment: sorry can some one edit my question.I am unable to do properly

Comment: Can you paste an "After" image too?

Comment: @mplungjan i am trying to draw that.Here second image and third image need to come in one collumn

Comment: He wants to make a D-Pad pretty much.. like on an gaming controller

Comment: Yes exactly the same thing

Comment: Can u make a fiddle with the arrow images ....it would be easier for us to align them then

Comment: @BhumiSinghal some one edited my question which has second image

Comment: i get what u want exactly ... but can u please upload these arrow images in a fiddle ...then we would be able to play with the excat images

Comment: how i can upload to fiddle

Comment: @PSR: You can't — I don't know why he said to do that. [Imgur](http://www.imgur.com/), however, would work.

Comment: @icktoofay - first of all its a 'she' and second u can upload images to fiddle as external resources provided it uploaded on an image hosting site ...

Comment: @BhumiSinghal: I'm sorry, I made an incorrect assumption; I didn't mean to offend. I would have chosen slightly different words, though, recommending an image hosting service, as you admit that you can't upload images *directly* to JSFiddle.

Comment: @icktoofay - Yup no direct upload ...i guess i wrote a misleading statement ..and no offence  :)

Comment: can u check this link http://jsfiddle.net/Bxk8A/

Comment: in my code images are not displaying

Comment: @rab i posted my answer it is working perfectly.But i dont know this is the proper way for coding or not

Comment: @PSR did u test code in different browsers ?

Comment: about my code.Just wait i will check it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure how good this will suit your req as this uses more of positioning. Please check.

http://jsfiddle.net/RFHrp/

```
 a.left {
    top: 20px;
    left: 15px;
}
a.right {
    top: 20px;
    left: 55px;
}
a.top {
    top: 0px;
    left: 35px;
}
a.bottom {
    top: 45px;
    left: 35px;
}
.left, .right, .top, .bottom {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 50%;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't show up images though... in the fiddle :(

Comment: Since the image paths are not available ..they wont show up .. :)

Comment: when i use this all working fine but why the background colour missing

Comment: use http://placehold.it/ to add images to your fiddle. Just a tip.

Comment: @PSR do you have a background color for the div?

Comment: yes i have yellow.But i did not posted that code here

Comment: when i see in firebug the div is showing like hidden

Comment: if i remove     position: absolute; then it is showing colour and the alignment is showing as first image

Comment: Hmm position is necessary for this kind of alignment. check this.. http://jsfiddle.net/V4rGc/

Comment: no it is also not working in my page.all alignments are distrubed.Any how i am going with my answer only.Thanks u all

Answer (score 3):

A completely different solution would be to use a single image as a sprite. This can be more efficient as it reduces http requests.

**HTML**

```
<div style="position:fixed;z-index:1;">
    <div class="arrowContainer">
        <a class="left" href="javascript:{}">L</a>
        <a class="top" href="javascript:{}">U</a>
        <a class="bottom" href="javascript:{}">D</a>
        <a class="right" href="javascript:{}">R</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.arrowContainer 
{
    position:relative;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
}

.arrowContainer a
{
   background-image:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/RtaFK.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    text-indent:-9999px;
    display:block;
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    position: absolute; 
}

.arrowContainer .top 
{    
    top: -2px; 
    left: 15px;
    background-position: -24px top;    
}

.arrowContainer .left
{
    top: 15px;
    left: 0;
}
.bottom {
    bottom: 0;
    left: 15px;
    background-position: -52px 2px; 
}

.right {
    top: 15px;
    right: 0;
    background-position: -76px top; 
}
```

You may need to tweak the position of the elements and/or background images but this is a good start.

Use an image with a transparent background if you want to add a background colour.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tqH3m/1/

**Update**

Even better don't use images at all. You can use pure css and apply a background color to the container. HTML is the same as above

**CSS**

```
.arrowContainer 
{
    position:relative;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:#CCC;
}

.arrowContainer a
{
    text-indent:-9999px;
    display:block;
    width:0;
    height:0;
    position: absolute; 
}

 .top 
{    
    top: 0; 
    left: 15px;  
    border-left: 10px solid transparent;
    border-right: 10px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 10px solid black;
}

 .top:hover 
{    
    border-bottom: 10px solid #F00;
}

.left
{
    top: 15px;
    left: 0;    
    border-top: 10px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 10px solid transparent; 
    border-right:10px solid black; 
}

.left:hover
{
    border-right:10px solid #F00; 
}


.bottom {
    bottom: 0;
    left: 15px;
    border-left: 10px solid transparent;
    border-right: 10px solid transparent;
    border-top: 10px solid black;
}

.bottom:hover {
    border-top: 10px solid #F00;
}


.right {
    top: 15px;
    right: 0;
    border-top: 10px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
    border-left: 10px solid black;
}

.right:hover {
    border-left: 10px solid #F00;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tqH3m/2/

Comment: but when i apply background color for this it is not displaying properly

Comment: create the image with a transparent background and you should be ok

Answer (score 0):

### css

```
.left{

   left:

   top:

}
```

set values for all class like above

Jquery:

```
$('.left').css({'left':0,'top':0});
```

Comment: is it not working for me

Answer (score 0):

Can you use CSS position for the second and third images. You have to do something like this.

```
.top {position: absolute; top: <some value>; left: <some value>}
.bottom {position: absolute; top: <some value>; left: <some value>}
```

Comment: it is also not working

Comment: Check this http://jsfiddle.net/ardeezstyle/ZRzp9/

Answer (score 0):

finally i solved my problem using the following code.But i dont know can i use this way or not.But it is working for me.

```
<div style="position:fixed;z-index:1;background-color:yellow;border-radius:4px;">
 <div  style="float:left;margin-top:10px;">
 <a class="left" href="javascript:{}"><img src="images/leftarrow.png"/></a> 
 </div>
 <div style="width:23px;float:left;">
 <a class="top" href="javascript:{}"><img src="images/uparrow.png"/></a>
 <a class="bottom" href="javascript:{}"><img src="images/downarrow.png"/></a>
 </div>
 <div style="float:left;margin-top:10px;">
 <a class="right" href="javascript:{}"><img src="images/rightarrow.png"/></a>
 </div>
</div>
```